# java regular expression find and replace multiple

Tags: java, regex, search, replace

I am trying to replace following code using regex in my code base.

```
if(StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty(employee.getName())){

//java code
}
```

New code should be:

```
If(StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.trim(employee.getName()))){

//java code
}
```

I have written following code to perform the update.

```
String regEx = "StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty(.*)";
String replacement = "StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.trim$1)";
textFromFile.replaceAll(regEx,pattern);
```

output is:

```
If(StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.trim(employee.getName())){)

//java code
}
```

what is wrong in my code??? please help me

Comment: there are couple of typos in your question, the expected result starts with "if" not "If" and in the replaceAll it is not pattern but replacement

Comment: this cannot work actually as you have no idea how many parenthesis you will have inside StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex `()` is the capturing group. Your regex pattern is incorrect because where you meant to put literal brackets, you have instead only put a capturing group.

The correct regex pattern is:

```
"StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty\\((.+)\\)"
```

`\\((.+)\\)` means match a literal open bracket followed by (and capture) 1 or more of any character, followed by a literal closing bracket.

Testing:

```
String textFromFile = "if(StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty(employee.getName())){}";
String regEx = "StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty\\((.+)\\)";
String replacement = "StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.trim($1))";
String output = textFromFile.replaceAll(regEx,replacement);
System.out.println(output);
```

Input:

```
if(StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty(employee.getName())){}
```

Output:

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(StringUtils.trim(employee.getName()))){}
```

Comment: It's failing for the below code.

Comment: if(!StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty(employee.getName) && !StringFunctions.isNullOrEmpty(employee.getEmailId))

Comment: @venkat If you require a more complex solution, you will probably need to implement it using something other than Regex.